# Use 2 0 1 and 8 to make 67

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

**Use $2$ $0$ $1 $ and $8$ to make the number $67$**

RULES

1. You must use all 4 digits.
   Only the digits 2, 0, 1, and 8 can be used. 
   You can make multi-digit numbers out of the numbers. Examples: 20, 82, 2.8
2. The square function may NOT be used. Nor may the cube, raise to a fourth power, or any other function that raises a number to a specific power.
   You may use the ^ operation if you use a digit, for example, [(8 + 1)^2 - 0!] is acceptable (if you're trying to get 80), because 2, 0, 1, and 8 is used.
   However, [20 ^ 2 / 8 + 1] can't be used to get 51 because it uses an extra 2.
3. Sorry, but the integer function may NOT be used. Nor may the round, floor, ceiling, or truncate functions.
4. +, -, *, /, (), !, sqrt, ^, and !! may be used for functions.

**Please no brute-force methods. Good luck.**

I see that there are many answers. I like #3 because it doesn't use more than 2 factorials, but the most upvoted one gets the credit.

**Wow!** You guys are good!

Comment: Solve with 2017 or 2018?

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I'll fix that. Sorry. Sorry. Upvote, though.

Comment: You have my Up-Vote :D

Comment: Just confirming that you know this is possible

Comment: $8^2+0!+1=66$ dammit!

Comment: @user477343 also $8^2 + 0 + 1 = 65$, $80-12=68$, $8^2 + (1 \times 0) = 64$, $8^2 - 0 - 1 = 63$, and $8^2 - 0! - 1 = 62$ haha!!

Comment: Fun fact! $\frac{8!}{20}+1=2017$

Comment: Out of curiosity, why 67?

Comment: It makes no sense to permit sqrt but disallow square.

Comment: @Vicky it atcually makes swnse to disallow square. It would make the puzzle almost trivial.

Comment: @Marius, the stated reason to exclude square is because that would use the 2 (ie if you do want to square you have to do 8^2 and that counts as using the 2) and for consistency the same should apply to sqrt - if you want to use sqrt you should do 8^(1/2).

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ The 2 is implied, but I don't actually have to write it on the page. That's why sqrt is generally allowed in these types of puzzles.

Comment: 67 because it is the hardest number to get. Try 88, or 57. Easy, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

> $(8!!!!+1)\times2+0!\\=(8\cdot4+1)\times2+1\\=(32+1)\times2+1\\=33\times2+1\\=66+1\\=67$

and similarly, with the digits in order:

> $20!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - 1 + 8$, where $20!^{(17)}=20\cdot3=60$.

Comment: I think $8!! = 8 \times 6 \times 4 \times 2$

Comment: @Marius I think this is correct based on the definition of the quadruple factorial; it’s up to OP to decide whether the quadruple factorial is allowed as a valid operation for this puzzle. Great answer though, JonMark Perry!! Love it! :D

Comment: 8!!!! is a [multi-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials)

Answer (score 12):

> $$8^2 + \sqrt{\frac{0!}{.\bar{1}}} = 64 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{9}}} = 64 + 3 = 67$$
>  Not that $.\bar{1}$ is 0.111111... recurring.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)** and great answer, too! I see that you are familiar with the *Stack Exchange* community since you have been given the $+100$ reputation bonus (and correct me if I'm wrong, but have I seen you on Math.SE?); though I still suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) for more information (particularly [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the *Asking* section as you have not asked a question yet). Happy Puzzling! :D

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to Puzzling.

Answer (score 10):

> $8!!! - 12 - 0! = 8 \times 5 \times 2 - 12 - 1 = 80-13 = 67$

Comment: that is brilliant, but is your function after the 8 allowed???

Comment: don't know. I guess we'll find out

Comment: plus one and we will see :-)    didn't know that was possible...

Answer (score 2):

I base my answer on

> **75** (20 minus 18 in base 75 is 67 when converted back to decimal.)

Answer (score 1):

> (2+1)! [connects (multi-digit) with] 8-0! 
> 3! [connects (multi-digit) with] 8-1 
> 3*2 [connects (multi-digit) with] 7 
> 6 [connects (multi-digit) with] 7 
> 67

Answer (score 0):

> How about 2, 0 + 1, 8. If 2, 0 is in base 16 and 1, 8 is in base 27, it adds to 67 in base 10.

Comment: Please make use of the spoiler tag >!

Comment: Added spoiler tag.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I did not downvote.

Comment: +1 Why downvote??