# Use 2, 0, 1, and 9 to make 34

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

[Use 2 0 1 and 8 to make 67](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71748/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-67)

See above for the rules.

**Note that in this one, the year is $2019$, not 2018**

Whoever does this one will be rewarded with the answers for 1-100.

Hint

> Look at the tags. Also, there is more than one solution, but the simplest one will be accepted.

Comment: An extra $2$ yields $(2+0!)!^2−1-\sqrt{9}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

> $$\dfrac{102}{\sqrt{9}}$$

with just two operations.

Comment: Oh this is much better! I got trapped by lateral-thinking again ;p Great answer! :D

Answer (score 3):

If we're using lateral thinking, then

> rotate the 9 to make a 6, then we have $6^2 - 0! - 1 = 34$.

Comment: As always, El-Guest strikes again like a genius (+1) :D

Comment: you dont have to use lateral thinking, take square root of 9 then take factorial, it gives you 6 anyway.

Comment: @Oray that’s a good point, though I thought flipping the 9 minimized the operations used!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the `lateral-thinking` tag, so I decided to do it in the following way:

> $$2\times (0!+16)=34.\tag{$9=6\small\rm \:when \:rotated$}$$

This uses a similar approach as what was shown in [@El-Guest's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72494/use-2-0-1-and-9-to-make-34/72496#72496) and technically uses the required numbers in their order (namely $2$, $0$, $1$, $9$).

The following is another one less technical.

> $$\underbrace{(2+0!)}_{3}\|\underbrace{(1+\sqrt{9})}_{4}=34\tag{$\|=\small\rm concatenation$}$$

Comment: Clever answer mate (+1) :D

Answer (score 1):

Also consider:

> $${9 \choose 2} - 1 - 0!$$