# Use 1 9 6 2 in this order to make 75

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

I'm looking for a solution to make number $75$ with numbers $1$ $9$ $6$ $2$ in that order and the same rules as in [Use 2 0 1 and 8 to make 67](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71748/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-67).
Here a copy of those rules:

1. You must use all 4 digits.
   Only the digits $1$, $9$, $6$, and $2$ can be used in that order.
   You can make multi-digit numbers out of the numbers. Examples: $19$, $96.2$
2. The square function may NOT be used. Nor may the cube, raise to a fourth power, or any other function that raises a number to a specific power.
   You may use the ^ operation if you use a digit, for example, $(1 + 9)^6 - 2!$ is acceptable (if you're trying to get $999998$), because 1, 9, 6, and 2 are used.
   However, $19 ^ 2 / 6 + 2$ can't be used to get $62.166...$ because it uses an extra 2.
3. Sorry, but the integer function may NOT be used. Nor may the round, floor, ceiling, or truncate functions.
4. $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$ or $\frac{\Box}{\Box}$, $()$, $!$, $\sqrt{\Box}$, ${\Box}^{\Box}$, and $!!$ may be used for functions.

**Please no brute-force methods. Good luck.**

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so I've edited in the rules from the linked challenge (and added the same tags).

Comment: Let's please *not* make "near-miss", out-of-intended-order, or otherwise clearly non-pertinent answers here. They do not attempt to answer the posed puzzle, and will be deleted: puzzles with no [tag:lateral-thinking] tag do not invite such answers.

Comment: agreed, good point @Rubio!

Comment: People need to strick this bogus idea of "infinite square roots" of a number being 1.  They cannot be written down.  If you're going to use the square root symbol, write it a finite number of times, for starters.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

how about this?

> $$1\times 9/.6/.2$$

this is allowed right?

Comment: Wow, this is clever.

Answer (score 13):

Loophole that I discovered:

> allowing multifactorial also allowed us to multiply $x$ by any integer $<x/2$ using a certain number of  $!$s.

(1) Pretty much based on micsthepick's answer...

> $(1*9+6)/.2$
>  $=15/.2$
>  $=75$

(2) self-innovated:

> $(1+9)!!!!!!!/(.6-.2)$
>  $=(10*3)/.4$
>  $=75$

(3) self-innovated:

> $(-1+9)!!!-\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{6}}}}}}/.2$ (infinite \sqrt{}s)
>  $=(8*5*2)-1/.2$, (yes, according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255834/nested-radical-eventually-reaches-1/3255839#3255839))
>  $=75$

(4) self-innovated

> $(19+6)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!/2$
>  $=25!^{(19)}/2$
>  $=25*6/2$
>  $=75$

Comment: Some notes regarding the multiple-factorials, OP didn't specify whether theya are allowed or not except for single and double factorials.

Comment: i think it is fine since it is in the linked question. thanks @athin

Comment: Gonna love #3 for insanity :D Good job on it!

Comment: Wow, I actually thought of the infinite square roots one, but didn't post it! +1 :)

Comment: No, "infinite square roots" is bogus.  1)  They cannot be *written* down.  2)  It is really a form/relative of a floor function.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is allowed, but

> $1 9 6 2$
>
>  $(1 {\sqrt 9}) + (62)$
>
>  $(1 3) + (62)$
>
>  $13 + 62$
>
>  $75$

Comment: the question does say that you can make multi digit numbers, but I would argue that it does not specifically allow the concatenation operator

Comment: if 1√9 = 13 then you can simplify it. (9-2)(6-1) = 75

Comment: No, that is not allowed for standard concatenation of digits.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that I found:

> $.1*((\sqrt{9})!)!+(6/2)$
>  $= .1 * 720 + 3$
>  $= 72 + 3 = 75$

Here is one similar to micsthepick's answer:

> $1*(9+6)/.2$

And here is a hybrid of the two:

> $1*((\sqrt{9})!)!/6!!/.2$
>  = $720 / (2*4*6) / .2 = 15 / .2 = 75$