# Use digits 3 3 5 to make 67 or 97

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Rules:

1. All 3 digits — $3$, $3$, and $5$ — must be used once each in any order. You can concatenate these digits to create multi-digit numbers (i.e. $33$).
2. You can use the factorial operation ($n!$), the subfactorial operation ($!n$) and the double factorial operation ($n!!$) (i.e. $3!=6$, $!5=44$, $(3!)!!=48$). However, extended multi-factorials ($n!!!...$) cannot be used.
3. $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$,$()$, $\hat{}$ can be used for functions.
4. You cannot use: round, floor, ceiling, truncate function or functions such as sin, cos, log.

Comment: Is sqrt allowed?  Also, what about repeating decimal operator?  Also, what about decimal points, such as ".3"?

Comment: Do you mean 67 and 97, or 67 or 97? 
If you mean or, consider giving @malioboro's answer a checkmark.

Comment: @Duck that answer uses concatenation after modifying the numbers, which is not the same thing as making a multi-digit number out of the original digits.

Comment: Same problem occurred here with my answer: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84834/use-1-9-6-2-in-this-order-to-make-75

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works for 97:

> $!(3!)-5!-(3!)!!=97$

Comment: @Neil W is there any way to combine our answers?

Comment: Nice find!  For those wondering, this simplifies to $265 - 120 - 48 = 97$

Comment: I don't even know how lucky I was to find this @JS1

Answer (score 9):

With a decimal point

> $67 = .5^{-(3!)}+3$

Comment: I like this much better than the one with concatenation, because with concatenation it is easy to make both 67 and 97.  Example: $5! - ((!3) || 3) = 120 - (2 || 3) = 120 - 23 = 97$

Answer (score 4):

( Partial answer)

for 67:

> $3! \Vert (!3+5) $

Comment: Wait, that's not partial, it says 67 **or** 97, not both. +1 :)

Comment: wait, that is a concatenation, isnt it? is that allowed??

Comment: Doesn't say concatenation isn't allowed.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I'm not pretty sure, actually. I think the first rule is said that we allowed doing something like concatenation

Comment: I think that is only applicable for the original numbers?

Comment: Yes, I have answered these types before (by @ThomasL) and that is what it usually means.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear about the concatenation. I just had in mind 33, 35, 53, so I would prefer a solution without a concatenation, where a digit is manipulated, but great findings!